# Weaken Dickson's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, prime-gaps

I'm interesting in Dickson's conjecture.
But it is hard to consider. I want some `weaken' Dickson's conjecture.
It is the following statement.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be constant integers. $S$ is a set of infinite primes. Then, the following statements are equivlant.
>
> 1. There are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $n+a$ and $n+b$ have only prime factors in $S$
> 2. There is an integer $n$ such that $n+a$ and $n+b$ have only prime factors in $S$

Is there a result for this weaker statement?

Comment: $2$ may need some clarification in terms of what the intended meaning is, similarly but to a lesser degree for $1$.  Is this the weaker version you wish to delve into?

Comment: Presumably you mean $S$ is an infinite set of primes, and all prime factors of $n+a$ and all prime factors of $n+b$ are in $S$.  But how is this a weakening of Dickson's conjecture?

Comment: it's a specific case applied twice.